# XSLT for flat to nested/hierarchical, with level interpolation?

Tags: xslt

Given this source XML document: **input.xml**

```
<body>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
  <p ilvl="3">content</p>

  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
  <p ilvl="3">content</p>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="3">content</p>
</body>
```

I'd like to transform to output.xml:

```
<list>
  <item>
    <list>
      <item>
        <p ilvl="1">content</p>
      </item>
      <item>
        <p ilvl="1">content</p>
        <list>
          <item>
            <p ilvl="2">content</p>
            <list>
              <item>
                <p ilvl="3">content</p>
              </item>
            </list>
          </item>
        </list>
      </item>
    </list>
  </item>
  <item>
    <p ilvl="1">content</p>
    <list>
      <item>
        <p ilvl="2">content</p>
```

etc

Attribute ilvl is the list level; its a zero-based index.

I tried adapting https://stackoverflow.com/a/11117548/1031689 and got output:

```
<rs>
   <p ilvl="1"/>
   <p ilvl="1">
      <p ilvl="2">
         <p ilvl="3"/>
      </p>
   </p>
   <p ilvl="1">
      <p ilvl="2"/>
      <p ilvl="2">
         <p ilvl="3"/>
      </p>
   </p>
   <p ilvl="1"/>
   <p ilvl="1">
      <p ilvl="3"/>
   </p>
</rs>
```

I have 2 issues with it:

- It doesn't create structure for any missing level (eg missing level 2 between 1 and 3), and
- The starting param level must match the first entry (ie 1 here).  If you pass 0, the nesting is wrong.

Before I tried this, I was using my own XSLT 1.0 code, attached below.

The tricky part is how to handle a decrease in nesting eg level 3 to 1:

```
  <p ilvl="3">content</p>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
```

**Updated**

I try to handle this in the addList template, as the recursion is "unwound", but its not quite right yet; in my output when it gets back to level 1 a new list is being inserted, but if I correct that, I drop the last 3 content items... If anyone can solve this, I'll be impressed :-)

Yeah, I know my code is way more complicated, so if there is any easy fix to the for-each-group approach above, it'd be great to have suggestions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- works, except makes new list for siblings -->

  <xsl:template name="listSection">
    <xsl:param name="last-level">-1</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="items"/>

    <xsl:variable name="currentItem" select="$items[1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentLevel">
      <xsl:value-of select="number($currentItem/@ilvl)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="nextItems" select="$items[position() > 1]"/>


    <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="$currentLevel = $last-level">
        <!-- just add an item -->
        <xsl:call-template name="addItem">
          <xsl:with-param name="currentItem"  select="$currentItem"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="nextItems"  select="$nextItems"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- that handles next level higher case, and level same case-->

        <!-- level lower is handled is addList template-->

      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$currentLevel &gt; $last-level">

        <xsl:call-template name="addList">
          <xsl:with-param name="currentLevel"  select="$last-level"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="nextItems"  select="$items"/> <!-- since haven't handled current item yet -->
        </xsl:call-template>

      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise> this level &lt; last level: should not happen?</xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>




  <xsl:template name="addItem">

    <xsl:param name="currentItem"/>
    <xsl:param name="nextItems"/>


    <xsl:variable name="currentLevel">
      <xsl:value-of select="number($currentItem/@ilvl)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <item>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentItem"/>

      <!-- is the next level higher?-->

      <xsl:if test="(count($nextItems) &gt; 0) and
                                        (number($nextItems[1]/@ilvl) &gt; $currentLevel)">
        <!-- insert list/item to the necessary depth-->
        <xsl:call-template name="addList">
          <xsl:with-param name="currentLevel"  select="$currentLevel"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="nextItems"  select="$nextItems"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </item>

    <!-- next level same-->
    <xsl:if test="(count($nextItems) &gt; 0) and
                                        (number($nextItems[1]/@ilvl) = $currentLevel)">

      <xsl:call-template name="addItem">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentItem"  select="$nextItems[1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="nextItems"  select="$nextItems[position() > 1]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template name="addList">

    <xsl:param name="currentLevel">-1</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="nextItems"/>

    <xsl:variable name="targetLevel">
      <xsl:value-of select="number($nextItems[1]/@ilvl)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="$targetLevel - $currentLevel &gt; 1">
        <!-- interpolate -->
        <list>
          <xsl:variable name="stuff">
          <item>
            <xsl:call-template name="addList">
              <xsl:with-param name="currentLevel"  select="$currentLevel+1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="nextItems"  select="$nextItems"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </item>
          </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:copy-of select="$stuff"/>

          <xsl:variable name="currentPos" select="count(msxsl:node-set($stuff)//p)" />

          <xsl:variable name="ascentLevel">
            <xsl:value-of select="number($nextItems[$currentPos]/@ilvl)"/>
          </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:variable name="ascentItems" select="$nextItems[position() > $currentPos]"/>

          <xsl:variable name="aftertargetLevel">
            <xsl:value-of select="number($ascentItems[1]/@ilvl)"/>
          </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:if test="(count($ascentItems) &gt; 1) and
                                    ($aftertargetLevel - $currentLevel = 1)">    
            <xsl:call-template name="listSection">
              <xsl:with-param name="last-level"  select="$currentLevel"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="items"  select="$ascentItems"/> 
            </xsl:call-template>

          </xsl:if>
        </list>


      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$targetLevel - $currentLevel = 1">
        <!-- insert real item -->

        <xsl:variable name="stuff">
          <list>
          <xsl:call-template name="addItem">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentItem"  select="$nextItems[1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="nextItems"  select="$nextItems[position() > 1]"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

        </list>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- might be items on the way out -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$stuff"/>

        <xsl:variable name="currentPos" select="count(msxsl:node-set($stuff)//p)" />

        <xsl:variable name="ascentLevel">
          <xsl:value-of select="number($nextItems[$currentPos]/@ilvl)"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="ascentItems" select="$nextItems[position() > $currentPos]"/>

        <xsl:variable name="aftertargetLevel">
          <xsl:value-of select="number($ascentItems[1]/@ilvl)"/>
        </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:if test="(count($ascentItems) &gt; 1) and
                                    ($aftertargetLevel - $currentLevel = 1)">    
          <xsl:call-template name="listSection">
            <xsl:with-param name="last-level"  select="$currentLevel"/> 
            <xsl:with-param name="items"  select="$ascentItems"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:if>


      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--should not happen!-->
      </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:call-template  name="listSection">
      <xsl:with-param name="items"  select="*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>


  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In the post you have cited, there are both 1.0 and 2.0 solutions, and they are very different. If you're constrained to XSLT 1.0 you need to say so, because this kind of problem is so much easier in 2.0.

Comment: Not constrained to 1.0 (except by my skillset!); in fact, using Saxon 9.7.0.7, so thanks for that :-)

Comment: In the title 'with level interpolation', and in the body, '[OP's attempt] doesn't create structure for any missing level (eg missing level 2 between 1 and 3)'. That's pretty clear to me. I'd offer a solution, but you really need an XSLT2 solution for this one, I don't really know XSLT2 as well as 1.

Comment: As Flynn says, the requirement has been there all along.  Sorry you didn't notice it Dimitre, and thanks for your efforts anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my second attempt to provide solution to the problem which, in its current state forces people (at least me) to guess what is wanted:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pStartLevel" select="1"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="p"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p
                            [not(@ilvl >= current()/@ilvl)][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <list>
    <item>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', '')[1]" mode="start">
        <xsl:with-param name="pParentLevel" select="$pStartLevel"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pSiblings" select="key('kChildren', '')"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </item>
  </list>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p" mode="start">
   <xsl:param name="pParentLevel"/>
   <xsl:param name="pSiblings"/>
   <list>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$pSiblings">
      <xsl:with-param name="pParentLevel" select="$pParentLevel"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </list>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
   <xsl:param name="pParentLevel"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[@ilvl - $pParentLevel > 1]" 
                        mode="buildMissingLevels">
     <xsl:with-param name="pParentLevel" select="$pParentLevel"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[not(@ilvl - $pParentLevel > 1)]" mode="normal">
     <xsl:with-param name="pParentLevel" select="$pParentLevel"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p" mode="normal">
   <xsl:param name="pParentLevel"/>
   <item>
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="start"
             select="key('kChildren',generate-id())[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="pParentLevel" select="@ilvl"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pSiblings" 
             select="key('kChildren',generate-id())"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
   </item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p" mode="buildMissingLevels">
   <xsl:param name="pParentLevel"/>
       <item>
         <p ilvl="{$pParentLevel +1}"/>
         <list>
           <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
             <xsl:with-param name="pParentLevel" select="$pParentLevel +1"/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>
         </list>
       </item>   
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<body>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
  <p ilvl="3">content</p>

  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
  <p ilvl="3">content</p>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="1">content</p>
  <p ilvl="3">content</p>
</body>
```

**produces what I believe is wanted**:

```
<list>
   <item>
      <list>
         <item>
            <p ilvl="1">content</p>
         </item>
         <item>
            <p ilvl="1">content</p>
            <list>
               <item>
                  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
                  <list>
                     <item>
                        <p ilvl="3">content</p>
                     </item>
                  </list>
               </item>
            </list>
         </item>
         <item>
            <p ilvl="1">content</p>
            <list>
               <item>
                  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <p ilvl="2">content</p>
                  <list>
                     <item>
                        <p ilvl="3">content</p>
                     </item>
                  </list>
               </item>
            </list>
         </item>
         <item>
            <p ilvl="1">content</p>
         </item>
         <item>
            <p ilvl="1">content</p>
            <list>
               <item>
                  <p ilvl="2"/>
                  <list>
                     <item>
                        <p ilvl="3">content</p>
                     </item>
                  </list>
               </item>
            </list>
         </item>
      </list>
   </item>
</list>
```

Comment: Nice work @dimitre thanks for perservering in spite of unclear input :-)

Comment: @JasonPlutext, I am glad that this time I guessed correctly. please, in future question don't hide important parts of the wanted result by the phrase "etc". :)