# XSLT: Using a key with a result tree fragment?

Tags: xslt-2.0

Following on from my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274065/xslt-for-flat-to-nested-hierarchical-with-level-interpolation), the p elements I want to apply the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40479279/1031689) to are actually in a result tree fragment.

How do I make the key function:

```
 <xsl:key name="kRByLevelAndParent" match="p"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p
                            [not(@ilvl >= current()/@ilvl)][1])"/>
```

match against p elements in a result tree fragment?

In that answer the key is used via apply-templates:

```
 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <list>
    <item>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kRByLevelAndParent', '')[1]" mode="start">
        <xsl:with-param name="pParentLevel" select="$pStartLevel"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pSiblings" select="key('kRByLevelAndParent', '')"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </item>
  </list>
 </xsl:template>
```

I'd like to pass my result tree fragment as a parameter, and have the key match p elements in that.

Is this the right way to think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no result tree fragments in XSLT 2.0 and later, you simply have temporary trees. As for keys, they apply to each document and the `key` function simply has a third argument to pass in the root node or subtree to search so assuming you have your temporary tree `$var` you can use `key('keyname', key-value-expression, $var)` to find elements in `$var`.