# Make in XSLT a TOC of the heading nodes inside an ul li structure

Tags: xml, xslt, html-lists, html-heading

### General overview

I try to make the table of content (TOC) of a document by picking only his heading nodes like h1, h2… h9 (`h[0-9]`).

These heading nodes should be structured in cascading `<ul>`-`<li>` structure where all the `<hN+1>` depending of an `<hN>` should be an `<ul>` included himself in the `<li>` of `<hN>`.

### Example

To be more explicit, let’s see this example. If I have the following file `document.xsl`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<document>
<h1>Lorem <i>arepo</i> ipsum dolor</h1>
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
<p>
Sed ut <i>perspiciatis</i> unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>

<h1>sit amet et consectetur</h1>
<h2>Quia adipit</h2>
<h3>aliquam quaerat</h3>
<p>
Sed ut <i>perspiciatis</i> unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<h2>Erit et nunquam</h2>

</document>
```

Then the expected rendering should be:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Lorem <i>arepo</i> ispum dolor</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></li>
        </ul>
    <li>
    <li>
        <span>Sit amet et consectetur</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Quia adipit</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <span>aliquam quaerat</span>
                    </li>
                <ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Erit et nunquam</span></li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

### Minimal working example

For the moment, I have this `maketoc.xslt`

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[self::h1 | self::h2 | self::h3 | self::h4 | self::h5 | self::h6 | self::h7 | self::h8 | self::h9]"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h6 | h7 | h8 | h9">
    <li>
      <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::h1 | self::h2 | self::h3 | self::h4 | self::h5 | self::h6 | self::h7 | self::h8 | self::h9]"/>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Ignor anything else -->
  <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Current rendering

But, this MWE generate this output:

```html
<ul>
   <li>
      <span>Lorem arepo ipsum dolor</span>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
            <ul/>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
      <ul/>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span>sit amet et consectetur</span>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <span>Quia adipit</span>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <span>aliquam quaerat</span>
                  <ul/>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span>Quia adipit</span>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <span>aliquam quaerat</span>
            <ul/>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span>aliquam quaerat</span>
      <ul/>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span>Erit et nunquam</span>
      <ul/>
   </li>
</ul>
```

#### The problems

As you can see, their is some problems with this MWE:

1. The firsts descending nodes in a same siblings are processed many times. They are processed as much as their depth. As example “aliquam quaerat” appear tree times because he is an `<h3>` node.
2. A useless `</ul>` appears sometimes inside a `<li>` who haven’t any `<ul>` inside.
3. The nodes who are not the firsts betwean theire siblings are treated as if they was `<h1>`. (See the case of “Erit et nunquam” who is an `<h2>`.

### The question

How to make the heading nodes of an xml inside a cascading `<ul>`-`<li>` structures with the descendants well related to their ascendants?

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: If you are limited to XSLT 1.0, you will find something quite similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295892/3016153.

Comment: I think `h6` is the maximum allowed by the HTML standard.

Comment: @y.arazim yes but in cases where my XML contain heading node higher than h6, I am able the put his rank inside an HTML class. It’s not really a problem for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have adapted the answer from [Converting flat hierarchy to nested hierarchy in XSLT depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295763/converting-flat-hierarchy-to-nested-hierarchy-in-xslt-depth) to the problem presented here.

This is an XSLT 1.0 solution but to me it seems more elegant than the XSLT 2.0/3.0 approach suggested in the other answer.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="h2|h3|h4|h5|h6" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[name()=concat('h', substring-after(name(current()), 'h') - 1)][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="/document">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="h1"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6">
     <li>
        <span>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
        </span>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', generate-id())"/>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution is truly fine and, as you said, _elegant_. BTW, sometimes under an <h2> theire is no <h3> but directly <h4> (or higher number). So your code doesn’t process it because it include an `name(current()), 'h' -1` and suppose all the intermediate levels are used. But it isn’t always true.

Comment: @fauve The same point was raised in a comment to the original answer, and a solution was also proposed there.

Comment: I found the discussion about it, but I didn’t find the solution for it.

Comment: The solution is to compare the substrings after 'h' using the < operator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XSLT 3 (or 2 but below is using some XSLT 3) this is a task for recursive grouping using `for-each-group group-starting-with`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="headings" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$headings" group-starting-with="*[local-name() = 'h' || $level]">
      <xsl:if test="self::*[local-name() = 'h' || $level]">
        <li>
          <span>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </span>
          <xsl:where-populated>
            <ul>
              <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(tail(current-group()), $level + 1)"/>
            </ul>
          </xsl:where-populated>
        </li>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <ul>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(*[self::h1 | self::h2 | self::h3 | self::h4 | self::h5 | self::h6 | self::h7 | self::h8 | self::h9], 1)"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<xsl:sequence select="mf:group(*[self::h1 | self::h2 | self::h3 | self::h4 | self::h5 | self::h6 | self::h7 | self::h8 | self::h9], 1)"/>` has the selection from your original code, I would probably tend to write it as `<xsl:sequence select="mf:group(h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h6 | h7 | h8 | h9, 1)"/>`.

As for your comment as seemingly to use an older version Saxon not supporting XSLT 3.0, you would need to replace the XPath 3 expression `'h' || $level` by `concat('h', $level)`, the XPath 3 function `tail(current-group())` by `subsequence(current-group(), 2)` and then, for the `xsl:where-populated`, you need some more work by replacing the whole `xsl:where-populated` and contents with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="tail-of-group" select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)"/>
<xsl:if test="$tail-of-group">
  <ul>
   <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($tail-of-group, $level + 1)"/>
  </ul>
</xsl:if>
```

The XSLT 3 declaration `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` needs to replaced in XSLT 2 by spelling out

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried to process this xslt with `saxon-xslt -o output.txt document.xml maketoc1.xslt and I get `Error at xsl:sequence on line 31 of file:maketoc1.xslt:
  Unknown XSLT element: sequence
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported`. Naturally, the output file is empty.

Comment: Currently supported versions of Saxon are 11 and 12 for Saxon Java, 10 for .NET framework, 12 for SaxonC, 2.5 for SaxonJS. I don't know what saxon-xslt is, perhaps a Linux package, I would hope there is one using a version of Saxon supporting XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.8 or later, as that exists since 2017.

Comment: There seems to be a package https://pkgs.org/download/libsaxonhe-java using Saxon 9.9 HE which definitely supports XSLT 3.0.