# How to group adjacent xml elements in nested ol with xslt v2.0 or 3.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document without proper hierarchy that I need to turn into a multilevel nested ordered list.

How to generate multiple-level ordered lists from the following source XML by grouping the elements into nested ordered lists based on the value of the name attribute?

The name attribute values that need to be grouped range from level_1 to level_6, so getting an XSLT transform to make the nesting more generic will really help. The elements with name level_0 name attribute value and all the other elements should be ignored or unchanged.

```
<root>
    <p name="level_0">Value excluded from grouping.</p>
    <p name="level_1">Value 1</p>
    <p name="level_1">Value 2</p>
    <p name="level_2">Value 3</p>
    <p name="level_2">Value 4</p>
    <p name="level_1">Value 5</p>
    <note>Some text</note>
    <p name="level_1">Another Value 1</p>
    <p name="level_2">Another Value 2</p>
    <p name="level_2">Another Value 3</p>
    <p name="level_3">Another Value 4</p>
    <p name="level_3">Another Value 5</p>
    <p name="level_4">Another Value 3</p>
    <note>Some text</note>
    <p name="level_4">Another Value 4</p>
    <p name="level_1">Another Value 5</p>
    <p name="level_0">Value excluded from grouping.</p>
</root>
```

The expected results should look like this

```
<ol class="ol-">
    <li class="li-level_1">Value 1</li>
    <li class="li-level_1">
        Value 2 <ol class="ol-level_2">
            <li class="li-level_2">Value 3</li>
            <li class="li-level_2">Value 4</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="li-level_1">Value 5</li>
    <li class="li-level_1">
        Another Value 1
        <ol class="ol-level_2">
            <li class="li-level_2">Another Value 2</li>
            <li class="li-level_2">
                Another Value 3
                <ol class="ol-level_3">
                    <li class="li-level_3">Another Value 4</li>
                    <li class="li-level_3">
                        Another Value 5
                        <ol class="ol-level_4">
                            <li class="li-level_4">Another Value 3</li>
                            <li class="li-level_4">Another Value 4</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <li class="li-level_1">Another Value 5</li>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I have tried the following xslt but the output is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <ol class="ol-{@name}">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@name">
        <li class="li-{@name}">
          <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          <ol class="ol-{@name}">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <li class="li-{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please say what version of XSLT. A problem like this is going to be much easier in XSLT 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: You might find this paper interesting: it tackles a very similar problem: https://www.saxonica.com/papers/ideadb-1.1/mhk-paper.html

Comment: Seems very similar to the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77214383/3016153.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKay, I have updated the xslt version. I can use 2.0 or 3.0.
I also appreciate you sharing the paper.

Comment: Thanks @y.arazim for mentioning the similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive grouping, here done with XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="items" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$items" group-starting-with="p[@name = 'level_' || $level]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::p[@name = 'level_' || $level]">
          <li class="li-{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:where-populated>
              <ol class="ol-level-{$level + 1}">
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(tail(current-group()), $level + 1)"/>
              </ol>
            </xsl:where-populated>
          </li>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="p[@name]">
    <li class="li-{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <ol class="ol-">
       <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(p[@name = (1 to 6)!('level_' || .)], 1)"/>
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin Honnen, the function seems to work well for my needs. I will conduct more testing on it and revert with questions, if any.

Comment: How to modify the function so that all other elements are unchanged?

Comment: @EBamba, can you raise that as a separate question where you show the exact output you want when on the one hand parts of the flat input is transformed into nested list but on the other hand you want to keep "other elements unchanged"? It is not clear how the output would look and obviously it is an additional requirement you should raise in a new, separate question.