# Flat structure with gaps to nested/hierarchical using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Yes, I know some of the answers, e.g. [Flat to Nested structure based on attribute value using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113161/flat-to-nested-structure-based-on-attribute-value-using-xslt) but there is a difference that matters to me.

Given is the following **flat XML structure**. The level information **may contain gaps**. There can be any number of **elements *without* level information** between the elements containing level information. Such elements should be **assigned to the previous element** with level specification.

```
<doc>
  <item>
    <meta>
        <text>abc</text>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
      <para>
        <level>1</level>
        <title>a</title>
      </para>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
      <para>
        <level>2</level>
        <title>b</title>
      </para>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
      <para>
        <level>1</level>
        <title>c</title>
      </para>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
      <para>
        <level>2</level>
        <title>d</title>
      </para>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
      <para>
        <level>2</level>
        <title>e</title>
      </para>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
      <para>
        <level>4</level>
        <title>f</title>
      </para>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
      <para>
        <level>1</level>
        <title>g</title>
      </para>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
        <text>def</text>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
        <text>ghi</text>
    </meta>
  </item>
  <item>
    <meta>
      <para>
        <level>2</level>
        <title>h</title>
      </para>
    </meta>
  </item>
</doc>
```

The result after the transformation should look like this ...

```
<text>abc</text>
<test title="a">
   <test title="b"/>
</test>
<test para="c">
   <test title="d"/>
   <test title="e">
      <test para="f"/>
   </test>
</test>
<test title="g">
    <text>def</text>
    <text>ghi</text>
   <test title="h"/>
</test>
```

My approach to the transformation is as follows.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="child" match="item"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::item[(meta/para/level) &lt;= ((current()/meta/para/level) - 1)][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="/doc">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[(meta/para/level) = 1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <test title="{meta/para/title}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', generate-id())"/>
        </test>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, I can not find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child1" 
         match="item[meta/para/level]"
         use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::item[meta/para/level &lt; current()/meta/para/level][1])"/>

<xsl:key name="child2" 
         match="item[meta/text]"
         use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::item[meta/para/level][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[meta/para/level = 1] | key('child2', '')"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[meta/para/title]">
    <test title="{meta/para/title}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child1', generate-id()) | key('child2', generate-id())"/>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[meta/text]">
    <text>
        <xsl:value-of select="meta/text"/>
    </text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

I have added a `root` element to make the result a well-formed XML.

Comment: Excellent idea to use two keys. That did the trick - thank you.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help with the following question (because there is a flaw in the only answer given): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690535/5743760